# How do I find a bunch of files with a string in its filename (or body text) and then move all those files to a specific folder?

Tags: find, rename, filenames, search

Say - what if I wanted to move every HTML file in several independent directories with the word "heavengames" in its filename (and as a second question, every HTML files with the word "heavengames" in its body text) to a new directory named "heavengames-threads"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To move files with the word in its name:

```
find /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 /and/so/on -type f -iname "*heavengames*" \
-exec mv -t /path/to/heavengames-threads {} \+
```

To move files with word in its body:

```
find /path/to/dir1 /path/to/dir2 /and/so/on -type f -exec grep -q heavengames {} \; \
-exec mv -t /path/to/heavengames-threads {} \+
```

ps. to check that all is correct, add `echo` before `mv` at the first run.

Answer (score 2):

In zsh or bash ≥4, based on the file name:

```
mkdir heavengames-threads
mv **/*heavengames*.html heavengames-threads/
```

For more flexibility (for example, to recreate the directory hierarchy, look up [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv)(there are [many examples on this site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Bzmv)).

Use `grep` to search the file contents. With recent versions of GNU utilities (i.e. on non-embedded Linux or Cygwin):

```
grep -RZ heavengames . | xargs -0 mv -t heavengames-threads/
```

For more portable commands, use `find`. See [Rush's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40812/how-do-i-find-a-bunch-of-files-with-a-string-in-its-filename-or-body-text-and/40815#40815).